# jquery validate errorPlacement wrapInner errorElement

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate, errorplacement

I have a problem with `errorPlacement`. I have a table and I want to display errors after tr which has input with invalid value. Error shoud be inside tr and td, to properly display. I'm trying to wrap the error element(tr) by td and it works but only once. I enter invalid value, then get error in tr and td (correct), then I enter valid value and again invalid and then error element is inserted only to tr. Td does not appear. 
Here's my **jquery code**:

```
 if ($('.predict_score').length > 0) {
        var $predict_score_form = $('#predict_score_form');
        $predict_score_form.validate({
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent().parent());
                error.wrapInner('<td colspan=100%>');
            },
            errorElement: 'tr'
        }); 

        $('.team_score_field').each(function() {
            $(this).rules('add', {
                digits: true
            });
        });
    }
```

and html:

```
<div class="predict_score">
  <form id ="predict_score_form" action="" method='post'>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th><th>&nbsp;</th><th>&nbsp;</th><th>&nbsp;</th><th>&nbsp;</th><th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>    
        <tr>
            <td >    <span>11.09.2013 13:30</span></td>
            <td >
                Reading FC                                        </td>
            <td>

                <input type="text" value="" name="">
                <strong>:</strong>
                <input type="text" value="" name="">

            </td>    
            <td>
                Stoke City                                        </td>
            <td>-:-</td>
            <td class="right"></td>
        </tr>        
        <tr>
            <td >    <span>11.09.2013 00:00</span></td>
            <td >
                Toronto FC                                        </td>
            <td >    
                <input class="team_score_field" type="text" value="" disabled="disabled" name="">
                <strong>:</strong>
                <input class="team_score_field" type="text" value="" disabled="disabled" name="">    
            </td>    
            <td>
                Chicago Fire                                        </td>
            <td>-:-</td>
            <td class="right"></td>
        </tr>     
        <tr><td colspan="100%"><input type="submit" value="" class="green_btn"></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
  </form>
</div>
```

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var $predict_score_form = $('#predict_score_form');
$predict_score_form.validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.find('td').attr('colspan', '100%')
        var $etr = error.closest('tr');
        $etr.insertAfter(element.closest('tr'));
    },
    errorElement: 'td',
    wrapper: 'tr',
    submitHandler: function(){
        return false;
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FRcgN/)

Comment: It works but when value is correct, span is hidden and there is unnecessary space between tr's. I want to hide tr, so errorElement must be tr

Comment: Still the same effect. During first validation everything works fine, tr with error is hiden, but I entered again wrong value and then error appear in tr, without td inside. I think tr with error shoudn't be removed after success, then we could display it again but how can I do this? I think I would have to change plugin code..

Comment: @StanisławaKrystyna last attempt... updated to use the `wrapper` property

Comment: seems to be working BUT .. :P how can I set to errorElement colspan=100% ? Because now it displays below first td, not on the entire width of tr

Comment: Thanks Arun very much! I had to add in stylesheet display: table-cell!important to .error because it still didn't display one the entire width. I know that !important is a bad habit but I have to admit that I have no energy for that anymore.. Thank you :)